# Differentiation via the Complex Exponential

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I just wanted to compare approaches and answers to this question! :)

For some reason, when I differentiate the question, my answer is in terms of only trigonometric functions. I'm only asking because I feel as though the answer should include some terms of hyperbolic functions.

Thank you so much!

[Question Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMvPr.png)

[My Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWkDo.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I don't know if your result is correct or not, but it does contain hyperbolic functions: $e^x=\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)$ and $e^{-x}=\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry! I will learn how to do so before I post again

Comment: @Botond Thank you I didn't consider that, I will take that into account and edit the question so it's in a better format

Comment: @SmithH: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=67th+derivative+cosh(t)+cos(t)

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Your answer does not make sense. There is at least a couple of unpaired parentheses.